# Does facebook multicast or unicast a live video?

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, video-streaming, multicast

I was wondering if Facebook uni-cast or multicast an ongoing live video streaming to a group of users. For example, if a user joins a live stream, will he/she get a separate uni-cast or multi-cast stream.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot rely on multicast working over the Internet across different ISPs, because many ISPs don't run the required protocols and haven't made the necessary agreements between each other.

Unicast is practically guaranteed to work, although it costs Facebook more; but it also allows clients to receive different streams based on connection quality and supported codecs.